# VLC opens and closes immediately when I play video files

Tags: vlc, mp4

I made a clean install on my laptop yesterday and installed VLC via command line.

VLC crashes immediately as soon as I play any `MP4` file. `MP3` files play fine.

I reinstalled Ubuntu. The problem persists.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. VLC version 2.2.2 Weatherwax.

I get a dialog "Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same problem, but VLC closed itself immediately after opening MP4 files as well. I have two graphics cards in my laptop, from Intel and NVidia, and apparently VLC has some issue with that (but doesn't actually output any error for me, running Manjaro). Changing the default for opening MP4 files from `vlc` to `prime-run vlc` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

Open VLC Player go to Tools in upper bar and select Preferences. Switch to Video settings, disable Accelerated Video Output and change Output to OpenGL or try other options if OpenGLs are not working.

Comment: Thanks mate. There are 16 output modes and I tried playing my video with every single on of them.
But, no luck !

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem. My problem was solved using this

```
sudo apt --reinstall install libgbm1
```

Comment: Not worth it, My system totally crashed after applying this command.
It was so much resky, please don't try this. I already wasted couple hours on it.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. VLC crashed as soon as I opened an mp3 or mp4 file. However, I managed to fix it on my machine by running the following commands.

Note: Uninstall the current VLC, if any, then run the commands

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install snapd

$ sudo snap install vlc

I then restarted my machine, and everything was working as expected.